# XQuartz / X11 removed when OSX updates

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

Every time OSX decides to update itself, it removes my XQuartz installation, which is required to use X11.

Apple no longer supports or ships X11, but why does it keep removing my third-party installation when it updates itself?  Is there any way of stopping it from removing XQuartz?

This has happened during the last two OSX updates - Mountain Lion, Mavericks.

Comment: Maybe this is a question for http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I installed to Maverick & my xQuartz was NOT removed. xQuartz is still working fine, i had the latest ML version of xQuartz installed.

Answer (score 0):

XQuartz isn't removed on updates.  Full OS updates remove the /usr/X11 and /usr/X11R6 symbolic links to /opt/X11, and that is a bug in the OS upgrade scripts.  You shouldn't need those symlinks unless you have legacy X11 applications that were built against Mac OS X 10.7 or earlier rather than against XQuartz.